# How do I to pass html cell id to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a sign up page for people to select open time slots for an event booth.  I've hijacked code from "phpmyreservation" but I need specific dates.  So I've created two arrays. One for "Day" and One for "Time". The combination of these two values are the id of the each table cell and are values stored in the MySQL table with the person/group that has chosen to man the booth on that date and time.

Assuming I need code to replace "void(0)" and a script that would put the $Aday and $Atime into one or two php variables.

How do I pass the HTML TABLE CELL ID to PHP variables?

```
<?php
echo '<table><tr><td></td> ';

foreach($global_days as $Aday) {

    echo '<th>'.$Aday.'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach($global_times as $Atime) {

    echo '<tr><th class="reservation_time_th">' . $Atime . '</th>';

    foreach($global_days as $Aday) {
        echo '<td><div id="div:' . $Aday . ':' . $Atime . '" onclick="void(0)">' . read_reservation($Aday, $Atime) . '</div></div></td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

This may be useful:
https://github.com/olejon/phpmyreservation

I think I've made progress, but I'm still stumped 
I changed:

```
onclick="void(0)"
```

to 
    onclick="process(\'' . $Aday . '\',\'' . $Atime . '\')"

and
created the js file:

```
function process() {
      var theDay = Aday;
      var theTime = Atime;
      var request = $.ajax({
                       type: 'post',
                       url: 'reservation.php',
                       dataType: "html",
                       data: { Aday: theDay, Atime: theTime }
                     });

      request.done(function(msg) {
          alert ( "Response: " + msg );
      });

      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      });
```

and added to php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['theDay']))
  {
    $day = $_POST[$theDay];
    $time = $_POST[$theTime];
  }
```

The page appears to work to some extent but not... $day & $time are null

Comment: Please, specify your question. You shouldn't expect people to write the code for you.

Comment: Thanks DreamWave... Is my Subject not clear?  I'm not sure I'm asking the right question...  I've added it again in the body, but again, I'm not sure I've got the nomenclature correct.

Comment: I'm trying to write my own code as I would prefer and as @DreamWave suggests..
I've replaced.. [    onclick="void(0)">'    ]  with  [    onclick=reservation.php?cellid="' . $Aday . ':' . $Atime . '">'   ]         No Joy..

Comment: consider using AJAX. then write a function which you call instead of `void(0)` and pass the id as argument, e.g. `onclick="myFunction(this.id)"`.

Comment: @SaschaP  I've attempted to create an Ajax function, but I'm missing something,  Maybe I'm missing a lot..  I did add the include...I'd appreciate feedback on how close I'm coming.

Comment: @SaschaP  Thanks for your efforts..  This was a goose chase.  I got it working but don't understand why it works the way it does.  Remember I was using code for PHPMYRESERVATION.  It uses "mysqli_real_escape_string()".  It expects a string with 3 colons and day and time are the 2nd and 3rd values.  With <Div Id=xxx:$day:xxx:$time> the code works as written above. I can't figure out how this string is defined.  Anyway, thanks for looking at this.  I removed the AJAX call as it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your if statement, a blank response is expected.

You need to check `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` since you are making a POST request and of course output something.

```
if(isset($_POST['theDay']))
  {
    $day = $_POST[$theDay];
    $time = $_POST[$theTime];
    echo $day . " " . $time;
  }
```

Also, you have to make `process()` accept parameters. So your code would look like:

```
function process(Aday, Atime) {
      var theDay = Aday;
      var theTime = Atime;
      var request = $.ajax({
                       type: 'post',
                       url: 'reservation.php',
                       dataType: "html",
                       data: { Aday: theDay, Atime: theTime }
                     });

      request.done(function(msg) {
          alert ( "Response: " + msg );
      });

      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      });
}
```

And your `onclick` attribute would look like `onclick="process($Aday, $Atime)"`.